# Use of undefined constant 'products' - laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

Below is my code for tutorial i am doing. but when i run my application, i get an writing

> > Use of undefined constant ‘product’ - assumed '‘product’' in Category.php

Why could this happening

PS: Sorry for my english

**Category**

```
 public function products()
   {
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
   }    
 public function check_items() 
   {    
    return $this->select(‘product’, DB::raw('count(*) as e.count'))->products()->groupBy(‘product’)->get();  
   }
```

**Product**

```
 protected $fillable = ['product'];

    public function shop() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Shop::class);
    }

    public function category() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

**View**

```
 @forelse ($shop->products as $item)                        
    @foreach ($item->check_items as $p )
     <div>{{$p->product}} ({{$answer->e.count}})</div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Looks like you have edited your code with a word processor rather than a text editor. The quotes around `‘product’` are not simple single quotes as they should be. Use a test editor like `notepad++` is free and very good unless you have something else already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using smart quotes for some reason:

```
‘product’
```

Use single quotes:

```
'product'
```

Notice the thickness and the more angled nature of the top quotes as opposed to the second version.

Consider using an IDE / code editor, VSCode, Atom or PhpStorm.

Comment: :) We seem to be pretty much in sync :)

Comment: :) that quote goes on to say `"fools seldom differ"` :) Lets hope we are not the fools

Comment: @RiggsFolly so you do learn something new everyday! I never knew that, thanks.